# Vim: Looking for Help to Create Custom Syntax Highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Here is what I got so far:

```
syntax match cfg_Comment '#.*$' contains=cfg_DocTag
syntax match cfg_DocTag  '#\s*\zs[\\@]\l\+' contained

highlight default link cfg_Comment Comment
highlight default link cfg_DocTag  SpecialComment
```

Works perfectly for something like:

```
##
#   @brief The maximum.
#    @type number
# @default 1
```

What I want to do next is to highlight the next word after `@type` with `Type` group. So I did the following:

```
syntax match cfg_Comment '#.*$' contains=cfg_DocTag,cfg_DocField_type
syntax match cfg_DocTag  '#\s*\zs[\\@]\l\+' contained

syntax match cfg_DocTag_type   '@type' containedin=cfg_DocTag nextgroup=cfg_DocField_type skipwhite
syntax match cfg_DocField_type '\a\+' contained

highlight default link cfg_Comment       Comment
highlight default link cfg_DocTag        SpecialComment
highlight default link cfg_DocField_type Type
```

There are 2 issues with this:

1. Now `@type` is not highlighted, and I get it because obviously I didn't specify the group for it, but I expected it to sort of inherit the color from its parent container `cfg_DocTag`.
2. Of course now everything in comments is of `Type` color and not just the word after `@type`, and I get it again because I specified that `cfg_Comment` is a container of `cfg_DocField_type`.

I know where the issues stem from, but I don't know how to elegantly solve them and write as less boilerplate code as possible.

Finally, can someone tell me why

```
syntax match cfg_DocTag_type '@type' containedin=cfg_DocTag nextgroup=cfg_DocField_type skipwhite
```

and

```
syntax keyword cfg_DocTag_type @type containedin=cfg_DocTag nextgroup=cfg_DocField_type skipwhite
```

are not the same? I.e. in the first case it's as I described above: `@type` is no longer highlighted since the group is not specified, but this is expected. But in the second case, it is highlighted even though the group is not specified, which is unexpected, so it feels like as a keyword it doesn't match at all. And it is easily provable with the simplest test case possible:

1. Highlighting works:

   ```
   syntax match Test '@type'

   highlight default link Test Keyword
   ```
2. Highlighting doesn't work:

   ```
   syntax keyword Test @type

   highlight default link Test Keyword
   ```

### Update

---

Following Ingo's answer the proposed solution indeed works. However what is interesting to me is why this one doesn't?

```
syntax match cfg_Comment '#.*$' contains=cfg_DocTag
syntax match cfg_DocTag  '#\s*\zs[\\@]\l\+' contained

syntax match cfg_DocTag_type   '@type' transparent containedin=cfg_DocTag nextgroup=cfg_DocField_type skipwhite
syntax match cfg_DocField_type '\a\+' contained

highlight default link cfg_Comment       Comment
highlight default link cfg_DocTag        SpecialComment
highlight default link cfg_DocField_type Type
```

This one would be perfect if only it worked. It frees us from duplication of the comment match, and does the natural inheritance. Omitting `@` before `type` does not change anything by the way, i.e. the inheriting effect stays intact. But why `cfg_DocField_type` is not highlighted? Any ideas?

Comment: Sry for my noobish question, but can you please explain what you did exactly? Just put everything in `vimrc`?

Comment: @bashophil: Of course not! If you extend some standard syntax highlighting that already comes with Vim, say for `cpp`, then you'd put your own `cpp.vim` to `.vim/after/syntax`. If you are writing something new from scratch or want to completely override the standard one that comes with Vim, say `cpp`, then you'd put to `.vim/syntax`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close already. Your containment of `cfg_DocTag_type` in `cfg_DocTag` doesn't work because they would both match at the same position. Leaving off the leading `@` from the former would fix it, but the `nextgroup=cfg_DocField_type` still wouldn't match, because apparently the end of the match for `cfg_DocTag` (after the tag) makes Vim not apply the `nextgroup`.

What I've done is putting `cfg_DocTag_type` on the same level as `cfg_DocTag`, i.e. not contained in the latter. There's only the duplication of the pre-match `#\s*\zs` as a downside.

```
syntax match cfg_Comment '#.*$' contains=cfg_DocTag,cfg_DocTag_type
syntax match cfg_DocTag  '#\s*\zs[\\@]\l\+' contained

syntax match cfg_DocTag_type   '#\s*\zs@type' nextgroup=cfg_DocField_type skipwhite
syntax match cfg_DocField_type '\a\+' contained

highlight default link cfg_Comment       Comment
highlight default link cfg_DocTag        SpecialComment
highlight default link cfg_DocTag_type   cfg_DocTag
highlight default link cfg_DocField_type Type
```

Re 1.: It is **not** contained; only if you leave off the `@`. Then, adding `transparent` would get you the inheriting effect.

Re "finally": I suspect that `@` is not part of `'iskeyword'` (it's not by default), but it has to be for `:syn keyword`.

Protip: Syntax script development is easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

Comment: Thanks, Ingo, as usual - high-quality answer! Please, take a look at my update as I have one more question.

Comment: As I said, if you extend the match for `cfg_DocTag` to include (some of) the `DocField_type` (e.g. ` '#\s*\zs[\\@]\l\+\s\w'`, only then it matches. The `nextgroup` doesn't apply when the parent's match end. I can't find a supporting statement in the help, though.